# Design a CLI with click which supports multiple arguments with unlimited parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, command-line-interface, python-click

I'm trying to build a command line interface, which accepts two lists of unknown size as parameters.

It is supposed to look something like this:

```
gitalizer plot something --users user1 user2 user3 --repository repo1 repo2 repo3
```

I'm using Click for designing the CLI and I'm facing an, in my opinion, weird limitation.

`click.argument` allows to specify `nargs=-1`, but it's impossible to have multiple `click.argument`s with `nargs=-1` since we can't determine where one argument ends and the other begins.

`click.option` would seem to be obvious choice for this, but somehow `click.option` doesn't support `nargs=-1` and always needs a fix size of arguments.

My question is now:
How do I build a CLI with click in such a way that it accepts two lists of unknown size.

Comment: I just tested the code in the duplicate and works fine for your use case.